Why can the temperature of the CMB change if it depends only on $z_{rec}$ and $T_{rec}$ which are constants?
How is it possible that the RHS is constant but the LHS will have a different value in the future?
$$ T_{CMB} = \frac{T_{rec}}{1+z_{rec}} $$

The relation between scale factor and redshift is
$$ \frac{a}{a_0} = \frac{1}{1+z}\ ,$$
where $a$ is the scale factor when the light was emitted and $a_0$ the scale factor when the light is observed.
Since the blackbody radiation temperature is proportional to the inverse of scale factor, we can equally write
$$\frac{T_0}{T} = \frac{1}{1+z}\ . $$
In your scenario, the fixed quantity in this equation is $T = T_{rec}$.
Hence
$$ T_0 = \frac{T_{rec}}{1+z}$$
$$ z = \frac{T_{rec}}{T_0} - 1\ .$$
But since $T_0$, the observed tempersture of the CMB continues to decrease as the scale factor increases, then $z$, the redshift of the CMB will increase.

$z_{rec}$ is not a constant. As the universe expands, the redshift increases.

Is it not the redshift at a specific time? The time of recombination?

No, the redshift is a dimensionless parameter that encodes how much the universe has expanded since the event.

"Redshift at a specific time" makes no sense. Redshift can only ever occur between two events. The redshift between an event and itself is always zero, just like the distance between you and yourself is zero.
